# How to stop a for loop by advancing the std::map iterator?

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, stdmap

I'm iterating through a `std::map` twice through using an outer `for` loop and a nested `for` loop. I want stop the inner loop when the condition is met. I know that if I call break, it will stop both the loops. I don't want that. I only want to stop the inner `for` loop.

My code snippet is as below:

```
    for(auto markerCounter = ellipsePropertiesMap.begin(); markerCounter != ellipsePropertiesMap.end(); markerCounter++)
    {                                    
        for(auto markerCounter2 = ellipsePropertiesMap.begin(); markerCounter2 != ellipsePropertiesMap.end(); markerCounter2++)
        {
            if(conditionMet)
            std::advance(markerCounter2, ellipsePropertiesMap.size());
            //I also tried the following:
            //markerCounter2 = ellipsePropertiesMap.end();
            //markerCounter2++;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to stop the inner for loop by advancing the iterator by the size of the std::map, but it's not working. I also tried to get the ending iterator and advance it to end the loop. Apparently that isn't working either.

So, how can I actually stop the inner loop?

Thanks.

Comment: `break` affects only one loop

Comment: How complex is the condition?  Do you need to do anything special if the condition is meet besides ending the loop?  Often times it can be added to the condition part of the loop itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want stop the inner loop when the condition is met.

`break` will do that exactly.

Alternatively, you might be able to make that condition part of the loop-condition.

> I know that if I call break, it will stop both the loops.

You knew wrong.

---

> ```
> std::advance(markerCounter2, ellipsePropertiesMap.size());
> ```

This would be valid if and only if `markerCounter2 == ellipsePropertiesMap.begin()`. If the condition is satisfied on any other iteration than the first, you increment the iterator past the end and have undefined behaviour. Also, this iterator advancement doesn't break out of the loop body, which will be executed until the loop-condition is checked for the next time.

> ```
> markerCounter2 = ellipsePropertiesMap.end();
> ```

This would dis-satisfy the loop condition, causing the loop to stop at the end of current iteration. However executing

> ```
> markerCounter2++;
> ```

after it would again increment past the end and have UB.